# How to remove underline from text input in react native from ios and android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can't seem to be able to remove the underline in text input from react native on ios and android. There is a prop underlineColorAndroid and I tried to set it to transparent but that didn't work. I actually made my own border and the underline still is there. I am wondering how I can remove that.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use.

```
underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
```

This should remove the underline by making it transparent.

Comment: Actually I had a wrapper style that had bottomborder with light grey color. I didn't realize that. Thanks though.